# Взятие массива из строкового ресурса

Tags: java, android

Как взять массив из строкового ресурса и поместить в массив String? 
Попробовал так, не получилось:

В классе:

```
String[] planets = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planet);
```

Строковый ресурс:

```
<string-array name="planet">
    <item>Марс</item>
    <item>Земля</item>
    <item>Юпитер</item>
    <item>Меркурий</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: Что значит "не получилось"?

Comment: Должно работать, я делаю аналогично. Разве что если это класс, а не активность, то доставать String из ресурсов нужно через context. Я передаю контекст в класс и далее из него достаю ресурсы: `String[] notifireArray = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.notification_array);`

Comment: выкладывайте больше кода и стактрейс ошибки

Answer (score 1):

```
// загрузка массива строк из res/values/arrays.xml в текстовое поле textStrings
String[] names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names);
for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    textStrings.append("Name[" + i + "]: "+ names[i] + "\n");
} 

// загрузка массива целых чисел из res/values/arrays.xml в текстовое поле textDigits
int[] digits = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.digits);
for(int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
    textDigits.append("Digit[" + i + "]: "+ digits[i] + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В string.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="planet">
        <item>Марс</item>
        <item>Земля</item>
        <item>Юпитер</item>
        <item>Меркурий</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

И в классе:

```
String[] planets = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planet);
```

Только что проверил, все работает.

Comment: Ошибка:

at com.simulator.role.PlayGame.<init>(PlayGame.java:20)

Comment: Вы же вызываете так: planets[0], planets[1], и т.д.?

Comment: @user207012, вы указали файл и строку, где у вас ошибка. Но, т.к. мы не видим ваш файл и тип ошибки эта информация полностью бесполезна. Вам надо указать тип ошибки, stackTrace и саму строку где она возникает. Без этого помочь вам невозможно.